# Why the value in csv file which less than thousand could not display 2 decimal places in excel but display in notepad++?

Tags: excel, csv, decimal, wicket

[image]

The csv file is generated by java program. The file I open notepad++, the values are in 2 decimal places as in the picture above shown. But when I open the file in excel, some values which less than thousand is not in 2 decimal places format. 
Why it behaves like that?

Code is like.

```
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", symbols);

    fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(detailsContent.getAppliedAmount() == null ? "" : "\"" + formatter.format(new BigDecimal(detailsContent.getAppliedAmount()).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)) + "\""));
    fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(detailsContent.getAmountSaving() == null ? "" : "\"" + formatter.format(new BigDecimal(detailsContent.getAmountSaving()).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)) + "\""));
```

Comment: and what has this got to do with Java?

Comment: the csv file is generated by java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the numbers that are greater than 1000, Excel sees that the string from the CSV uses a thousand separator character, so it applies a number format to the cell. It takes its cue from the text, i.e. thousand separator and two decimals. If there were no thousand separator in the source, Excel would apply the General format.

With the smaller numbers, Excel applies the General format, which will omit zeros as decimals. The fact that the source file has two decimals is not a sufficient trigger for Excel to apply a specific number format.

Comment: So, is that any solution to display the smaller numbers in format? thank you very much.

Comment: Excel interprets the text in the CSV file and turns it into a number format. Sometimes Excel gets it wrong. The only way to ensure the numbers are formatted how you want them is to actually select the cells in Excel and set the formatting. It's only a few clicks.